# Ruby, Watir Classic and IE: Browser stops unless it has focus

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, cucumber, watir

After upgrading our test quite from Watir 2  to Wait-classic 3.6 we've discovered that unless IE is on an interactive desktop and has focus our test scripts stop until they timeout or someone gives IE focus.  Since we run 5k tests nightly on our grid, this is a bit of a problem.

We're running IE8 on Windows 7 and have been running this suite without issue for more than a year.

Hopefully someone else has seen this behavior and can provide some insight.

Comment: Are the tests using a lot of sendkeys type actions?  that's the only thing I've seen that seems to care what the focus is.

Comment: Can you show the error which appears when you're getting timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past when testing IE with watir where there were actions in the browser where we had to resort to using 'sendkeys' a lot (due to some rather obstinant custom javascript based controls) we noticed that IE seems to startup with the focus on the URL line of the browser, and unless that was shifted, those actions failed

So one of the first things our tests did was use sendkeys to send a 'tab' just to the browser object, and that seemed to serve to get the focus within the browser session onto the 'window' area of the browser and not the url field.

You might try that and see if it makes a difference for you.

Comment: I'll test this tomorrow but it sounds like it might be the culprit.

Comment: I'm guessing since you accepted the answer that this worked for you?